# how to unzip a zip file at installation of application and before start my application in android

Tags: android

i have a zip file in my assets folder and i want unzip that file at installation time and before start my application.so does it possible to unzip a file during installation..
pleaze help me solve this out..

i have done this on my splash screen and it's working but want to do it at the time of installation of my application and before my splash screen.

public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

```
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private Context context;
AssetManager assetManager;
InputStream is;

String Url = "http://remote.careerfinity.com/User/UI.zip";
String unzipLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/unzipFolder/";
String StorezipFileLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/DownloadedZip";
String DirectoryName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/unzipFolder/files/";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    //assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("Device-Initial-UI-Files.zip");

    Thread timer = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent gotoStart = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(gotoStart);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();  

}



public void unzip() throws IOException {
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SplashScreenActivity.this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();
    new UnZipTask().execute(StorezipFileLocation, DirectoryName);
}

public class UnZipTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        String filePath = params[0];
        String destinationPath = params[1];

        File archive = new File(filePath);
        try {
            ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(archive);
            for (Enumeration e = zipfile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
                unzipEntry(zipfile, entry, destinationPath);
            }

            Ziputil d = new Ziputil(StorezipFileLocation, DirectoryName);
            d.unzip();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    private void unzipEntry(ZipFile zipfile, ZipEntry entry,
            String outputDir) throws IOException {

        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            createDir(new File(outputDir, entry.getName()));
            return;
        }

        File outputFile = new File(outputDir, entry.getName());
        if (!outputFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
            createDir(outputFile.getParentFile());
        }

        // Log.v("", "Extracting: " + entry);
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                zipfile.getInputStream(entry));
        BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

        try {

        } finally {
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    private void createDir(File dir) {
        if (dir.exists()) {
            return;
        }
        if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can not create dir " + dir);
        }
    }
}





private void recursiveDelete(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
            recursiveDelete(child);

    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

}

Comment: at installation time? You can't.

Comment: hi,thank for rply.but can it not possible in any way ????

Comment: if is not possible, is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below class : -

```
public class Decompress
{
private Context mContext;
private Logger mLogger;

public Decompress(Context context)
{
    this.mContext = context;
    mLogger = Logger.getInstance(mContext);
}

/**
 * Unzips given zip file in specified location.
 * 
 * @param zipFile
 * <br>
 *            Passing zip file path - will search file in File directory. <br>
 *            Passing zip file name (without extension)- will search in apps
 *            raw folder.<br>
 * 
 * @param unZipLocation
 * <br>
 *            Pass path-location where 'zipFile' will be unzipped.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public void unZip(String zipFile, String unZipLocation)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println(">>> Start Unzip..." + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        InputStream fin = null;
        try
        {
            fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            int resId = mContext.getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(zipFile, "raw", mContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
            fin = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
        }

        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        int count;

        while((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null)
        {
            Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

            if(ze.isDirectory())
            {
                dirChecker(ze.getName(), unZipLocation);
            }
            else
            {
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(unZipLocation + ze.getName());
                byte data[] = new byte[128 * 1024];

                while((count = zin.read(data)) != -1)
                {
                    fout.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                data = null;
                zin.closeEntry();
                fout.close();
            }
        }
        fin.close();
        zin.close();
        System.out.println(">>> Unzip completed..." + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        mLogger.error(Logger.ERROR_CODE_API, e);
    }
}

private void dirChecker(String dir, String unZipLocation)
{
    File f = new File(unZipLocation + dir);

    if(!f.isDirectory())
    {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
}
}
```